# How to create a menu with category created in new template

Tags: magento2, extensions

I installed this template http://magento2.flytheme.net/themes/sm_shop4u/default and i followed this step : http://documentation.flytheme.net/sm-shop4u/#themesetting but ia m not getting my menu and can you please explain to me the meanning of data type when chosing category ??? i am really lost please if any one have an experinec with this template please help me and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

They have their own support system: https://www.magentech.com/submit-a-ticket/submit-ticket
Did you post a ticket for them?

Do you use their `Mega menu` extension for menu? Here is some extra info about it:
http://documentation.flytheme.net/sm-megamenu-2x/

Did you follow `SM Mega Menu` steps from tutorial?

Comment: yes i followed tutorial step by step but i can't get my menu

Comment: Finally i get the menu back

Comment: i still have problem with block and with the config of listings products

Comment: I don't think I can help you if you don't provide more info about the problem.